# Replacing FrameLayout in Activity by a Fragment does not replace the whole FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I'll give a brief description of my app layout. There is an Activity, inside it is a FrameLayout wrapped with a RelativeLayout (there are some other widgets too inside this Relative Layout), whose dimensions are set to 'Match Parent'. Inside the MainActivity, I do a fragment transaction, replacing that FrameLayout with a Fragment.

The one thing common between the Activity and Fragment is that they both have a Tab Menu at top. Now, when the Fragment replaces the FrameLayout, the Tab Menu of the Fragment is supposed to replace that of the Activity (FrameLayout is set to Match Parent dimensions). ***However, this does not happen.***

Only the RecyclerView in the Fragment shows above the RecyclerView of the Activity (I have one Recycler View each in the Activity and Fragment). The Tab Menu stays the same as that of the Activity.

This is very perplexing.
Am I missing something?

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s handle only `View`s that belong to `Fragment`s. They will not remove or replace any other `View`s that you might have in your layout. If you want your `Activity`'s original content replaced, the proper way to do that is to move that content into its own `Fragment` that you load at startup. The container `<FrameLayout>` should be empty.

Comment: @Mike What things should I keep in mind to migrate the Activity code to a fragment?

Comment: @MikeM. can you share an example of that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When moving from activity to Fragment,You need to set `View.Gone` on activity's views to achieve the desired view.**

You can remove activity views like that.

**In Activity, Before making Fragment Transaction,**

```
   //whatever view you want to remove//.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

When coming back from fragment to Activity, you should set View's Visibility back to visible.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but there's a lag though. Can I do something so that the user doesn't actually see this lag?